# Android - how to read screenshot without gallery intent

Tags: android, screenshot

I am interested in writing a screenshot app and want to learn the technique from this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tools.screenshot&hl=en).

After user takes a screenshot using power and volume buttons, the app opens up the screenshot without the user needing to pick an image from the gallery. I want to do something similar (save the user the step to navigate the gallery to get screenshots).

Does anyone how can an app read a screenshot as this app did ? (In the app's demo video this step is shown at time 0:30)

**Edit**

I've tried testing it on my nexus 5. I can see the screen shots are in folder `/sdcard/Pictures/Screenshots`. The directory permissions are:

```
drwxrwx--x   root   sdcard_rw   2015-08-30 01:42    Screenshots
```

I gave my app storage permissions. I used the following code in a service, but it didn't work:

```
FileObserver fileObserver = new FileObserver("/sdcard/Pictures/Screenshots") {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(int event, String path) {

            Log.d("Test", "FileObserver event");
        }
    };

    fileObserver.startWatching();
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be running as a service in the background, which register a [FileObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html), and perform action upon file added.

Or the service simply check the folder manually.

**Edit:**

`Warning: If a FileObserver is garbage collected, it will stop sending events. To ensure you keep receiving events, you must keep a reference to the FileObserver instance from some other live object.`

It means that local variable is definitely not working, put it into a field AND make sure your class will not be garbage collected, e.g. even Activity can be killed, and garbage collected afterwards.

Comment: Is there a standard directory path where screen shots are kept ?

Comment: seems it would be under `Pictures/Screenshots` in the primary storage , but there seems to have no documentation, so no guarantee

Comment: I believe it could be specific to manufacturer, but checking both primary and secondary (SD card) storages with Pictures/Screenshots, as case insensitive should find the folder

Comment: Please check the edit. I tried using FileObserver for test, but it didn't work.

Comment: updated, FileObserver is very difficult to use, check my edit. You probably need a service, even with a service, you have to make sure it would not be killed easily